# Special use of "with"

Tags: conjunctions

1. With so much on **her mind**, she can hardly sleep.
2. With so much to do, she can't afford to waste any time.
3. With that said, I'll wait to see if you have any follow-up questions.

I'm not familiar with such kind use of ***with***. I'll appreciate it if anyone discuss this special usage of ***with***, and suggest me the alternative ways to rewrite the above sentences.

Comment: It can be paraphrased " These circumstances being in effect..."  There's no need to rewrite, as it's perfectly idiomatic.  But you could say "Because she has so much on her mind..."

Comment: 1. could be rewritten "She can hardly sleep, with so much on her mind." 2. Could be rewritten "She can't afford to waste any time, with so much to do". but 3. Could be rewritten "That said, I'll wait to see if you have any follow-up questions."  The reason is that 3 contains a finite verb and is thus a finite clause. The other two are noun phrases. So 1 and 2 are grammatically quite different to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **With** so much on her mind, she can hardly sleep.

There is nothing "special" about this use of **with**. The whole clause "with so much on her mind" is a subordinate clause to "she can hardly sleep".

We can rephrase the whole sentence thus:

> When/because so much **is** on her mind, she can hardly sleep.

Since in "with so much on her mind" the verb **is** is absent, it's called a "verbless clause". Let's take away **is**:

> When/because so much on her mind, she can hardly sleep.

This sentence looks strange, since "**when/because**" does not work without a finite verb like **is**. That's why we need **with**:

> **With** so much on her mind, she can hardly sleep.

This word **with** is called by some authors a "subordinator" (short for "subordinating conjunction"). This subordinator "introduces" a verbless clause.

In your second example, the subordinator **with** introduces a to-infinitival clause:

> With so much **to do**, she can't afford to waste any time.

In your third example, the subordinator **with** introduces a participle clause (a "past participial" clause):

> With that **said**, I'll wait to see if you have any follow-up questions.

One other subordinator that works like **with** is **without**:

> **Without** you to consult, I would be completely lost.

Voila!

Both **with** and **without** require the presence of a noun or a noun phrase:

> With **so much** on her mind, she can hardly sleep. (the noun phrase is **so much**, and it serves as the subject of the verbless clause)

---

P.S. A rewrite for sentence 2:

> **When there is so much to do**, she can't afford to waste any time.

A rewrite for sentence 3:

> **That said**, I'll wait to see if you have any follow-up questions.

**That said** is more widespread than **with that said**.

You can also say:

> **Having said that**, I'll wait to see if you have any follow-up questions.

But this sentence would mean that it was the speaker who **said that**, while in the previous sentence that could be some other person.

---

References:

- Quirk et al. *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, Unit 14.15, "Subordinators for nonfinite and verbless clauses".